# In R, is there a way to calculate the number of days between the end of one event and the beginning of another?

Tags: r, dplyr, difftime

(*Note:  Hotel data used as illustrative example.*)

I'm working with a dataset that has multiple records (e.g. 'hotelStays') for each customer (custID).  My goal is to get the number of days since a customer's previous stay as a new column in the data frame (i.e. each customer's first stay would have 'NA' as its value).  To do so, I want to subtract each customer's previous checkOutDt from their current checkInDt.  However, when I attempt to do so using lag(), all values in the new column are 'NA'.

Below is an example of the type of data with which I'm working.

| custID | stayID | stayDt | checkInDt | checkOutDt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAAAA | 11111 | 01/15/1995 | 01/10/1995 | 01/17/1995 |
| BBBBB | 11112 | 02/08/1995 | 02/02/1995 | 02/25/1995 |
| AAAAA | 11113 | 03/01/1995 | 03/01/1995 | 03/03/1995 |
| AAAAA | 11114 | 06/24/1995 | 06/22/1995 | 07/02/1995 |
| BBBBB | 11115 | 10/02/1995 | 10/01/1995 | 10/10/1995 |
| CCCCC | 11116 | 01/08/1996 | 01/05/1996 | 01/17/1996 |
| AAAAA | 11117 | 05/15/1996 | 05/10/1996 | 05/28/1996 |

Ideally, the new column, 'daysSinceLastStay', would have the following values:

| daysSinceLastStay |
| --- |
| NA |
| NA |
| 43 |
| 111 |
| 218 |
| NA |
| 313 |

However, I think I need to sort by custID and stayDt first.

---

Below is my current attempt at the code:

```
hotelData <- hotelData %>%
                arrange(custID, stayDt) %>%
                mutate(daysSinceLastStay = 
                       checkInDt - lag(checkOutDt))
```

---

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the data you're expecting, it seems like you're needing to make use of the `group_by()` function. This should get you what you're looking for.

```
# t*r*ibble, for creating data by row
hotelData <- tibble::tribble(
  ~custID, ~stayID, ~stayDt, ~checkInDt, ~checkOutDt,
  "AAAAA",  11111,  "01/15/1995",   "01/10/1995",   "01/17/1995",
  "BBBBB",  11112,  "02/08/1995",   "02/02/1995",   "02/25/1995",
  "AAAAA",  11113,  "03/01/1995",   "03/01/1995",   "03/03/1995",
  "AAAAA",  11114,  "06/24/1995",   "06/22/1995",   "07/02/1995",
  "BBBBB",  11115,  "10/02/1995",   "10/01/1995",   "10/10/1995",
  "CCCCC",  11116,  "01/08/1996",   "01/05/1996",   "01/17/1996",
  "AAAAA",  11117,  "05/15/1996",   "05/10/1996",   "05/28/1996"
)

# convert the date columns to the proper data type
# then, sort the data by customer ID and stayID
hotelData <- hotelData %>%
  mutate(across(stayDt:checkOutDt, lubridate::mdy)) %>%
  arrange(custID, stayID)

# within each customer, take the difference in days
hotelData %>%
  group_by(custID) %>%
  mutate(daysSinceLastStay = as.numeric(checkInDt - lag(checkOutDt)))

# A tibble: 7 x 6
# Groups:   custID [3]
  custID stayID stayDt     checkInDt  checkOutDt daysSinceLastStay
  <chr>   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>                 <dbl>
1 AAAAA   11111 1995-01-15 1995-01-10 1995-01-17                NA
2 AAAAA   11113 1995-03-01 1995-03-01 1995-03-03                43
3 AAAAA   11114 1995-06-24 1995-06-22 1995-07-02               111
4 AAAAA   11117 1996-05-15 1996-05-10 1996-05-28               313
5 BBBBB   11112 1995-02-08 1995-02-02 1995-02-25                NA
6 BBBBB   11115 1995-10-02 1995-10-01 1995-10-10               218
7 CCCCC   11116 1996-01-08 1996-01-05 1996-01-17                NA
```

Comment: Thank you @Andrew!  Quick follow-up:  Why is the group_by(custID) here necessary?

Comment: Based on your description and the desired column output in your question, my understanding is that you're needing to compute times-from-last-stay on a per-customer basis. The `group_by()` function ensures that functions (such as `lag()`) are applied on a grouped basis, i.e. as separate data frames. In the case of my output, customer CCCCC hasn't had >1 stays, so you wouldn't want to use the last row of BBBBB's data (i.e. row #6).

Comment: Got it, thank you!  I had previously grouped that df but did not realize that doing so was necessary for each operation performed on a per-customer basis.  Makes sense, appreciate it.